# JQuery: Make hidden span visible and blink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK, I know blinking is bad, but I really need this.  When recording a phone call, I want the agent screen to blink "Recording."  Otherwise I don't want the word to appear.  I seem to be able to do one or the other, but not both.

```
<head>
<style> span { display:none; } </style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery.modern-blink.js"></script>
<Script>
function StartRecording($user) {
    $.get("http://172.16.77.22/script.php?agent_user="+$user+"& _
                function=recording&value=START", function( data ) {
    $( "#top_hr").show();
    $( "#bot_hr").show();
            });
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('.js-top-hr').modernBlink();
            $('.js-bot-hr').modernBlink();
    });
}
</script>
```

Here's a span that should be affected:

```
<span class="js-top-hr" id=top_hr><hr style="color:red"><font style="color:red">
<center>RECORDING </font></span></center>
```

...

Here's a button that should do the trick:

```
button id"="StartRec" name="StartRec" onclick="StartRecording('<?php echo _
     $user;?>');">Start Recording Now!</button>
```

(Had to take the open tag off "button because it would not display."

Any help greatly appreciated!

JR

Comment: What do you mean you can't do "both"?

Comment: I want it to become visible and blink.  I can make it appear and disappear with a button, or I can make it blink with a button.  Can't seem to get both.

Comment: As an aside, your `<center>`, `<span>`, and `<font>` elements are out of order in your span HTML code snippet. Could have something to do with preventing it from working.

Comment: Thanks, ElGavilan.  That made more elegant but did not change the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function StartRecording($user) {
    $.get("http://172.16.77.22/script.php?agent_user="+$user+"& _
                function=recording&value=START", function( data ) {
        $( "#top_hr").show().modernBlink();
        $( "#bot_hr").show().modernBlink();
    });
}
```

Comment: I noticed in the firefox 29.01 web console I'm getting 
    "TypeError: $(...).show(...).modernBlink is not a function"
but I have 
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery.modern-blink.js"></script>
and these source files are in the parent folder of the calling page.

Comment: Could not resolve the "modernBlink is not a function" by changing the location or the reference.  It just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This has been in production with my "work around" for months, but now I needed to get back to it.  I just re-cycled to this, and Kevin's answer worked as is.  Thanks Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with javascript/JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function(){
      $('.blink').each(function(){
        $(this).css('visibility' , $(this).css('visibility') === 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden')
      });
    }, 250);
</script>
<span class="js-top-hr blink">RECORDING</span>
```

Alternatively you could also use CSS3:

```
.blink {
  -webkit-animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
  animation: blink 1s step-end infinite
}

@-webkit-keyframes .blink {
  67% { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes .blink {
  67% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Then assign the `.blink` class when the button is pushed.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element)

Comment: How would I pass this the $user parameter?

Comment: Thanks, I made this work by putting <blink>TEXT</blink> tags in the way the wiki you referenced said.  I'm using 2 scripts, but it works!  I was going to vote up you answer but my reputation is insufficient.  But thanks!